# Is an RRSP always "self-directed"?  What makes a "self-directed" RRSP special?

Tags: canada, rrsp, self-directed

Based on this definition of self directed RRSP:
http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/selfdirectedrrsp.asp

It seems all RRSPs, by default, are self directed, because the 'owner determines the asset mix' always; as far as I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term *self-directed* generally refers to RRSP accounts where the account holder has not only the ability to determine a basic investment asset mix (such as can be accomplished even with a limited selection of mutual funds) but, more specifically, **the self-directed account holder has a much wider choice of financial instruments beyond mutual funds, GICs, and/or cash savings.**

A self-directed RRSP generally permits the account holder to also invest or trade *directly* in financial instruments such as:

- bonds (including governments and corporates),
- public company stocks/shares/unit trusts listed on a stock exchange,
- exchange-traded funds (ETFs),
- purchasing call and put options,
- writing covered call options,
- ... or even holding a mortgage on a property.

Those kinds of instruments are not typically available in a non-self-directed mutual fund or bank RRSP.  Typical mutual fund or bank RRSPs offer you only their choice of products  – often with higher fees attached.

Related resources:

- [GetSmarterAboutMoney.ca - Do I need a self-directed RRSP?](http://www.getsmarteraboutmoney.ca/managing-your-money/investing/rrsps-for-retirement/Pages/do-i-need-a-self-directed-rrsp.aspx)
- [Million Dollar Journey - Back to Basics: How Self Directed RRSP's Work](http://www.milliondollarjourney.com/back-to-basics-how-self-directed-rrsps-work.htm)